# How to disable windows USB support(Driver) and allow just a specific certified device

Tags: windows, usb, hook, driver

i'm working on a project where i need to create an "embeded system". for some issues i have an usb port which is free accessible to the public. i would like to develop a system where 
i can plugin an USB (standard windows format NTFS/FAT) but it will be accepted by windows system only if there is for example an specific file (certificate) on it, in any other cases windows system will not be able to access the file as a storage. (and of course no other storage will be allowed)

my first idea was to write a kernel hook or an driver.
but i'm not sure if i'm on the right way, because as i understand i would also need to write an ring 0 one? to prevent windows from using they standard usb drivers first?

any ideas?
any examples?

thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to develop a File System Filter driver. [Here is a link to a nice tutorial on Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43586/File-System-Filter-Driver-Tutorial). Also, [Rajeev Nagar's Windows NT File System Internals](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0976717514) will have the most helpful information on the topic.